# Swift 4 - send application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON

Tags: json, swift

I want to encode my JSON to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
var req = URLRequest(url: url)
req.httpMethod = "POST"
req = JsonHelper.defineCommonHeaders(request: req)
var headers = req.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
print(headers)

do {
    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(self)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    req.httpBody = jsonData as Data
    print ("httpBody is: ", jsonString)
} catch {
    //TODO:error handling
}
```

sending my JSON from Postman is fine, however sending from Swift 4 does not work.
I quess I need to encode empty key somewhere. There is great example [POST request using application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063959/post-request-using-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)
but it does not cover how to do it in Swift 4. What I have to change?

Comment: Have you tried adding another header: "Accept": "application/json"

Comment: I had. No luck. The problem is that `x-www-form-urlencoded` requires key: value (API of the client need key to be empty). But I have no idea how to add so basically it requires `""="{my_json_here}"`. I get this with manipulating strings, but it is still not accepting this.

Comment: Open postman, click on code, select language and try that code in your application.

Comment: Tried this already. No luck.

Comment: Could you show us the postman example? Why don't you just use `application/json`? In `x-www-form-urlencoded` you would have to URL encode the JSON string.

Comment: I have asked third party api provider to change to application/json. Then all working like a charm, and my code is much tidier.