# "{\"error\":\"unsupported_grant_type\",\"error_description\":\"Grant Type is NULL\"}"

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm getting a return response of:

> "{\"error\":\"unsupported_grant_type\",\"error_description\":\"Grant
>   Type is NULL\"}"

I have tried a few different ways to build the JSON string it wants but I'm not having any luck. I seen a few samples where people got it to work but they must have changed it.

Here is my code:

```
public string PostPayment([FromBody]Payment_DTO payment)
{
    //Request token
    var client = new RestClient(_EndPoint);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    string json = BuildTokenRequest();
    string svcCredentials = 
    Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_UserName + ":" + 
    _Password));

    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
    urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", json, 
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    return response.Content.ToString();
}
```

I think the issue is in my json builder function its self. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in here:

```
public string BuildTokenRequest()
{
    //string request = "grant_type=" + _Password + "&client_id=" + _UserName + "&client_secret=" + _Password + "$username=" + _UserName + "&password=" + _Password;
    string request = "client_id="+ _UserName + "secret=" + _Password + "grant_type=client_credentials";

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't produce anything resembling a worthwhile JSON object, it just serialises a simple string to JSON. When you do that, all you really get out of the other end is just... a simple string - because that's valid JSON already. The serialiser has no way to know you intended these to be separate fields, it just sees one long piece of text. It has no way to ascribe any extra meaning to it.

For example:

```
string _UserName = "123";
string _Password = "abc";
string request = "client_id=" + _UserName + "secret=" + _Password + "grant_type=client_credentials";
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
```

will output just

```
"client_id=123secret=abcgrant_type=client_credentials"
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DTDDjI

Now as I said, technically it's valid JSON, but it's highly unlikely to be what the remote server is expecting - again it will not know that it needs to parse that string and extract the values from it. I can't the spec of your remote API (as you haven't told us what endpoint you're calling or linked us to any documentation) but I imagine will be expecting an object with the values in separate fields. To get this kind of thing from the C# you need to start with a C# object to begin with:

For example:

```
string _UserName = "123";
string _Password = "abc";
var request = new { client_id = _UserName, secret = _Password, grant_type = "client_credentials" };
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
```

will output

```
{"client_id":"123","secret":"abc","grant_type":"client_credentials"}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCpMhV

Note the use of an anonymous object containing discrete fields to pass to the JSON serialiser, and then the object containing discrete fields which is the result.

As I say I can't check to see if this is precisely the layout which the remote server expects, but you should be able to check the documentation to see if that's correct or not. And if not, you now hopefully understand how to correctly generate a useful JSON object which would match the specification.

---

Another point. This line of your code:

```
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

is unnecessary. You can remove it because

a) it sets the wrong content-type for a request containing JSON and

b) the line below it will (as per the [RestSharp docs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest) set both the correct content-type header and the JSON body content in one call.

Comment: Hmm its for Paypal. So your suggestions structure it as a string array? I'll give it a shot thanks.

Comment: @mholmes Just for clarity, `{"client_id":"123","secret":"abc","grant_type":"client_credentials"}` is not an array, it's an object. If you don't know the difference or indeed the general structure of JSON objects, now might be a sensible moment to study it in a bit more detail.

Comment: I know Json fairly well, I don't understand PayPal documentation lol Thats why I'm here trying to figure out. Your likely right though its my structure of my json string.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my request was incorrectly encoded for the `"content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.
Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064061/2866275), I constructed my `request.httpBody` differently and it worked.